# Internet Explorer Versions(Except 9.0) Problems About CSS3 Shadow and List Properties

Tags: html, css

I've been searching about this issue for a couple of days. But as the problems are spesific, so the solutions usually are. My problem is kinda common but the solutions I found so far didn't work for me.

1. I use a #header div which is around 30 px height. Under that div, I have 3 divs like left, center and right. I have an accordion menu with js in the left div, content place in center, and last tweets script in the right div. Since I added box-shadow to #header div, other div's under it are placed after where shadow ends. I used z-index to make header div's shadow place on other div's, and it works perfectly in Firefox, Safari, Chrome, even IE9! But when I try in older versions of IE, it just happens the way I tell. Here is a screenshot: http://www.twitpic.com/4kh9w3
2. Like I just said, I have "last 2 tweets" script in the right div. It fills < ul> < li> items with tweets and shows them. So that I can design this list in my css file. And same, it only doesn't work for IE7&8. I don't even mention 6, it's not so important. The problem is that IE automatically scrolls list items to left. So half of them disappear! Here is the screenshot: http://www.twitpic.com/4khajz

So, what can I do to save my view in Firefox, Chrome etc. and also can fix it in Internet Explorer 7&8?

Comment: According to [link](http://www.deepbluesky.com/blog/-/browser-support-for-css3-and-html5_72/), IE 6, 7, and 8 don't support what you're trying to do.  I thought at much, which is why when I saw your post, "Wait, you're trying to use CSS3 in earlier versions of IE? Hah, good luck with that." So yeah, IE is a b--ch ain't it.

Comment: Can you provide links to the page or source for us to look at so we have something to work with?

Comment: Hi, I knew that IE doesn't support most of CSS3 abilities but I just wanted to know that if there is any alternative. Anyway, here's the link: http://pizzam.com.tr/yeni/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand your problem... but if you cant get shadows to work try looking here http://css3please.com

Comment: The problem is to find an alternative method for box-shadow and box-radius. Thank you.

Comment: you can use this for ie for shadows 

zoom: 1;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#000000', Direction=135, Strength=3);

Comment: Thanks, will try that. Do you know anything about space before list elements? I tried vertical-align-bottom, margin-left:0, padding-left:0, removing the space between </li> and new <li> element, I've tried everything. Actually just close approximately 20 tabs about this issue. Nothing works. IE7 sucks but customer doesn't know what Firefox is. Or Chrome, Safari, Opera...